# Referencing USB drive with os.walk() is not returning any files

Tags: python, tkinter

When I reference a USB drive plugged in to my rasberry pi with `os.walk('/media/pi/UNTITLED')` it's returning nothing but when I reference something in the same folder as the script (`os.walk('./movies')`) it works fine. I am not getting an error message either. Is it a permissions thing? Am I using an incorrect path? I can navigate to the USB drive in the terminal. See the code below for my whole script. Again I apologize for the length but I am not sure where I'm going wrong.

Thank you,
Mark

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import os.path
import re
import fnmatch
import math

class scareGUI:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        tfLogo = PhotoImage(file='tf_logo.gif')
        scareBtn = PhotoImage(file='scare_btn.gif')
        scareBtnStop = PhotoImage(file='scare_btn_stop.gif')

        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('cbfont.TCheckbutton',font=('Courier',16))

        #self.selectedFileName = StringVar()

        #filter non video file types
        includes = ['*.mp4']
        includes = r'|'.join([fnmatch.translate(x) for x in includes])

        master.attributes('-zoomed', True)

        logoLabel=ttk.Label(self.master,text="TerrorForm ScareBox", font=("Helvetica", 24))
        logoLabel.config(image=tfLogo)
        logoLabel.pack(fill=BOTH)
        logoLabel.image=tfLogo
        directionLabel = ttk.Label(self.master,text="Select the files below you would like the ScareBox to play.", font=("Courier",20,'bold'))
        directionLabel.pack(fill=BOTH, padx=10, pady=20)

        ttk.Separator(self.master,orient='horizontal').pack(side="top",fill=X,padx=20, pady=20)

        self.frame_files=ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame_files.pack(fill=X, padx=20)

        ttk.Separator(self.master,orient='horizontal').pack(side="top",fill=X,padx=20,pady=20)

        contVar=IntVar()
        playContinuousBtn = ttk.Checkbutton(self.master,text='Play movies in a loop without motion detection',style='cbfont.TCheckbutton',variable=contVar)

        playContinuousBtn.pack(side=TOP,padx=20, pady=20)

        frame_buttons = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        frame_buttons.pack(side=TOP)

        stopButton = ttk.Button(frame_buttons, text="I'm Affraid", command = master.destroy)
        stopButton.config(image=scareBtnStop)
        stopButton.config(compound=TOP)
        stopButton.image=scareBtnStop
        stopButton.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y,padx=10, pady=10)

        closeButton = ttk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Start Scaring!", command = master.destroy)
        closeButton.config(image=scareBtn)
        closeButton.config(compound=TOP)
        closeButton.image=scareBtn
        closeButton.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y,padx=10, pady=10)

        #pull file names from file system
        #for root, dirs, self.files in os.walk('./movies'):
        for root, dirs, self.files in os.walk('/media/pi/UNTITLED'):

            self.files = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in self.files]
            self.files = [f for f in self.files if re.match(includes, f)]

        #Determine number of rows in grid
        numfiles = len(self.files)

        dividesBy = False
        numRows = IntVar()
        numColumns = 4
        while (dividesBy == False):
            if(numfiles % numColumns == 0):
                numRows=int(numfiles/numColumns)
                dividesBy = True
            else:
                numfiles+=1


        #Print Check Boxes in Grid layout
        filmIcon = PhotoImage(file='tf_film_icon.gif')
        i=0
        self.checkedFiles=[None]*len(self.files)


        for r in range(numRows):
            for c in range(4):
                if (i<len(self.files)):
                   self.checkedFiles[i] = IntVar()
                   checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(self.frame_files, text=self.files[i], variable=self.checkedFiles[i])
                   checkbutton.config(image = filmIcon,compound = TOP)
                   checkbutton.image = filmIcon
                   checkbutton.grid(row = r, column = c)
                   i+=1


    def getChosenFiles(self):
        self.chosenFiles=[]
        for x in range(len(self.files)):
            if(self.checkedFiles[x].get()):
                    self.chosenFiles.append(self.files[x])
        return self.chosenFiles

    def main():
        root = Tk()
        scaregui = scareGUI(root)
        root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: Print root, dirs, and self.files to see what it returns.  You are doing more than just reading the directory so the problem could be further down the line.  I assume that the USB drive has been mounted correctly since you can navigate to it.

Comment: Curly, Thank you for helping me get a little further down the road.  I printed self.files before filtering for *.mp4 and it shows up. My question I guess now is why does the filter work when when walking "." as opposed to "/media/pi".

Comment: The `os.walk()` code to determine `self.files` works for me regardless of whether the folder path is relative (`'.'`) or absolute (`r'(D:\media\pi\UNTITED`) on my Windows system, so the path you're using to reference the USB drive must be wrong. Use whatever works with the `ls` or `dir` shell command on your system.

Comment: martineau, I am pretty sure I am using the correct path. When I print self.files before filtering i see my file and bunch of other stuff. After filtering I get nothing. It looks like each iteration of the walk loop overwrites the last.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `includes` might mess up things. I suggest making a small code snippet to test just if you can access that specific directory. Maybe something like:

```
import os

includes = ('.mp4',)

movie_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/media/pi'):
    files = [f for f in files if f.endswith(includes)]
    movie_list.extend([os.path.join(root, f) for f in files])

print('number of files: ', len(movie_list))
```

This will make a list of all files ending with `.mp4`, and print the number of files found. `movie_list` can be `self.movie_list` if you want to store it in a variable accessible by the class.

Comment: It looks like files is getting overwritten at each iteration of the loop so by the time it gets to the end there is nothing with .mp4 and it file count is zero.

Comment: I've figure out the problem now I just need a solution. My os.walk() regardless of the path is overwriting the variable as it goes into each subdirectory. It is not appending file names.

Comment: Of course, should have seen it before. Because it is storing the values into `self.files` (just `files` in my example), it will be overwritten each time the `os.walk` goes into a subdirectory and creates a new list of `self.files`. So the movie list needs to be an independent variable. Updating the example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I solved my own problem. I was not appending the file names to a list at the bottom of the loop. The fact that I had no subdirectories in my initial test caused me to falsely think it was working. My solution code is below.

```
matches=[]
for root, dirs, self.files in os.walk('/media/pi'):
    for filename in self.files:
        if filename.endswith(('.mp4','.mov','.avi')):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root,filename))
```